# SQL "In" condition with subquery

Tags: sql

I'm wondering what is the best way to do the following code:

```
 select Id,Id2 from someTable
 where Id in (select someId from someTable2)
    or Id2 in (select someId from someTable2)
```

I checked the execution plan and I can see two table scans(no index) for someTable2.

The solution I'm looking is not related to indexing but to a better way to construct this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JOIN`,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.ID, a.ID2
FROM    someTable a
        INNER JOIN someTable2 b
            ON b.someID IN (a.id, a.id2)
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT ID, ID2
FROM someTable a INNER JOIN someTable2 b ON b.someID = a.id
UNION
SELECT ID, ID2
FROM someTable a INNER JOIN someTable2 b ON b.someID = a.id2
```

Comment: how about using `UNION`? add index on the columns.

Comment: i have. I just wanted to make the example as simple as possible. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
     , id2
FROM   sometable
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT someid
         FROM   sometable2
         WHERE  someid IN (sometable.id, sometable.id2)
       )
```

Comment: there are still two sub-queries

Comment: @GZ answer updated. Yes, there were two sub-queries, but how did the query plan compare?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is an index on `someid` then any query will have to do a complete table scan.  You could *try* changing to a join:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT T1.Id,T1.Id2 
 FROM someTable T1
 LEFT JOIN someTable2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.someId 
 LEFT JOIN someTable2 T3 ON T1.Id = T3.someId 
 WHERE T2.someId IS NOT NULL 
    OR T3.someId IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: since this is inner join if t1 doesnt match t2 query will return no result even if t1 match t3.
check the following code:

 SELECT 1 AS id
 INTO #t1

 SELECT 2 AS id
 INTO #t2

 SELECT 1 AS id
 INTO #t3

 SELECT * FROM #t1
 JOIN #t2 ON #t2.id = #t1.id
 JOIN #t3 ON #t1.id = #t3.id